# How to call Bittrex API in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to call Bittrex API in Objective-C, but I receive the following message:

```
{
    message = "APIKEY_NOT_PROVIDED";
    result = "<null>";
    success = 0;
}
```

Here is my code:

```
- (void)fetch {

  double unixtime = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
  NSURLComponents *components = [NSURLComponents componentsWithString:@"https://bittrex.com"];
  components.path = @"/api/v1.1/account/getbalances";


  NSURLQueryItem *nonce  = [NSURLQueryItem queryItemWithName:@"nonce"  value:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",unixtime]];
  NSURLQueryItem *apikey = [NSURLQueryItem queryItemWithName:@"apikey" value:@"xxxxx"];
  components.queryItems = @[nonce,apikey];
  NSURL *url = [components URL];

  NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                                         cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                     timeoutInterval:10.0];


  [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
  [request setValue:[self sha512:components.query withSalt:@"xxxxx"] forHTTPHeaderField:@"apisign"];
  NSData *body = [components.query dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
  [request setHTTPBody:body];



  [[[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithRequest:request
                                   completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

                                     if (response && ! error) {
                                         NSLog(@"%@",  [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil]);
                                     } else {
                                         NSLog(@"%@", error);
                                     }

                                 }] resume];

}
```

Please let me know how to call Bittrex API.

**Environment**

macOS HighSierra
XCode 9.0.1
Objective-C

Comment: If you copy/pasted your code as-is, the line `NSURLQueryItem *apikey = [NSURLQueryItem queryItemWithName:@"apikey" value:@"xxxxx"];` does not contain your API key....

Comment: I hid API key by myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should generate the hash with the full URL.

```
[request setValue:[self sha512:url.absoluteString withSalt:@"YOUR API SECRET"] forHTTPHeaderField:@"apisign"];
```

And the following code is unnecessary.

```
NSData *body = [components.query dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
[request setHTTPBody:body];
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed answer.